# Mail function not working with user accounts

Tags: functions, email, user-registration, password

I have an issue with the user account system. It refuses to email people their passwords when they make and account and when they get a temporary password. It always returns with this error "The e-mail could not be sent. Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function." Now I know the server can email just fine. It is self hosted and the site is a virtual host along with a few other sites that email people with no issues. On top of that one of the extensions in the wordpress can email people just fine. I have heard this issue might be a database corruption but I really don't know. And if it is I don't konw how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Well had you asked host if it disabled `mail()` function (for this specific site/account maybe)? :) Unfortunately WP completely isolates error handling on email send, cannot get to real error message without forking and plugging over `wp_mail()`.

Comment: Again the site if self hosted, I own the server, I have full control of it. Besides logically if the server cut the sites ability to email people it wouldn't be able to send any emails and it can. The site has a plugin called "Easy Digital Downloads" installed and it can email people their receipts from the site just fine. But I'm not sure what you are asking for with the wp_mail().

Comment: What I meant is that whatever exception mail library used internally is throwing WP is isolating that information in code and gives you that error message instead. There is no way to get actual error from the underlying library without modifying `wp_mail()`.

Comment: Alright well how can I modify it to find out what is going on?